# How can I change the number of function parameters based on another parameter?

Tags: javascript, function, function-parameter

I have a JavaScript function like so:

```
myfunction(type, param1, param2, param3){
    //do stuff
}
```

In VS Code when you hover over a function you see function parameters required by the function. I wanted to change the required function parameters based on another parameter is that possible? I am trying to do this so that if another coder hovers over the function they can see the required parameters based on their first parameter.

How can I set that if I input a certain type, say `"type1"` then my function only requires `param1`. I am aware that by doing `param1=1` I can make `param1` optional. However, what I would like to achieve is to have function parameters disappear or appear based on another function parameter. For example if I input `type` as `"type3"`. I would want the next and last parameter to be `param3`, basically changing the number of parameters depending on another parameter.

How can I change the number of parameters based on another parameter in JavaScript?

Comment: You can use [the `arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) or [the rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), both are iterable and have a `length` property so you can know how many parameters were passed

Comment: If you want to keep params variable, may be in your case you can use rest operator- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: JavaScript doesn't really care about function arity, in TypeScript you can use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to represent this.

Comment: Paremeters in JavaScript are *always* optional and you can *always* pass as many as you want. So, it's not clear what you mean by making them "disappear" or "appear". The function signature is mostly a suggestion.

Comment: How are you using the parameters inside the function? Check [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to see if works for your scenario. You could also pass an object as the second parameter with appropriate key name and destructure it like this: `myfunction(type, { param1, param2, param3 })`. But, seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Sounds like you need just one `param`, and this parameter's value changes based on `type`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have learnt a lot. I have also updated the question.

Comment: Sounds like you need documentation, rather than altering the signature dynamically. Look up JSDoc and use it. Most editors tend to read it by default so you'd be able to see the documentation when you hover. Not sure if VS Code does it but at most it would require a plugin to be installed.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ I now understand the full scope of my issue.